# How to handle different screen resolutions for mobile phones in Unreal Engine? Specifically UI

Tags: android, user-interface, unreal-engine4

I have looked around but, I am unable to find an answer to my question. Basically, I am creating a phone app. The only problem I seem to be having is with the menu UI. Basically, it is set to a 1080x1920 resolution, which is probably the most common one out there. However, it is not the only one. How do I handle multiple screen resolutions? Do I need to make like separate widgets for each resolutions and load in the correct one based on that? Or is there some other way that I am just not aware of. I am sure that others have come across this same problem too.

The reason I bring this up is because I have loaded the app onto a phone that is not 1080x1920 and the UI doesn't fit inside of it. I have tried messing with different settings on the UI but, nothing seems to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @B001ᛦ I'm using UE4 not android studio

Answer (score 3):

There were two problems that were happening. The first reason why the UI wasn't scaling properly was because I was using a Size Box instead of just a plain Canvas Panel. It didn't matter what I did, the Size box would remain the same. Changing that would solve the first problem. The second problem that was happening was that because of the size box it forced my anchors to be centered instead of stretched. Once I replaced the Size Boxes with Canvas Panels I was able to make my panel anchors stretch to fill the screen.

I hope this helps anyone else that comes across this problem.

Comment: Thank you for providing a good answer to a rare question (albeit your own), It should help others.